# How to Unit Test an URI translated response?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing

I am trying to mock an URI translated response. however it is always throwing null during unit test. The code I am trying to mock is as follows:

```
  final URI sourceFileSftpLocation = routeBuilder.deleteFromSourceAndMoveToTargetSftpBuilder(fileName, config.getMerchantFilePath(), config.getFailedPath(), config)
.build();
```

My Unit Testing Class is as follows:

```
@InjectMocks
    ScaService scaService;
    @Mock
    BatchStatusService batchStatusService;
    @Mock
    BatchInvoker batchInvoker;
    @Mock
    PaymentHubConfigLookup paymentHubConfigLookup;
    @Mock
    JobExecution jobExecution;
    @Mock
    PaymentHubBatchTracking paymentHubBatchTracking;
    @Mock
    ScaRouteBuilder scaRouteBuilder;
    @Mock
    URIBuilder uriBuilder;

@Test
    public void existingFileTest() throws Exception {
        scaRouteBuilder = mock(ScaRouteBuilder.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
        uriBuilder = mock(URIBuilder.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
        uri = mock(URI.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);

        when(paymentHubConfigLookup.getMerchantName()).thenReturn("BarclaysSingle");
        when(batchStatusService.updateSpecificBatchFileState(any(), anyString())).thenReturn(paymentHubBatchTracking);
        when(paymentHubConfigLookup.getMerchantFilePath()).thenReturn("merchantFilePath");
        when(paymentHubConfigLookup.getFailedPath()).thenReturn("failedPath");

        //Not working mockings below
//        when(scaRouteBuilder.deleteFromSourceAndMoveToTargetSftpBuilder(anyString(), anyString(), anyString(), any()))
//                .thenReturn(uriBuilder);
//        doReturn(uriBuilder).when(scaRouteBuilder)
//                .deleteFromSourceAndMoveToTargetSftpBuilder(anyString(), anyString(), anyString(), any(PaymentHubConfigLookup.class));
//        when(scaRouteBuilder.deleteFromSourceAndMoveToTargetSftpBuilder(anyString(), anyString(), anyString(), any()).build())
//                .thenReturn(uri);
//        doReturn(uri).when(scaRouteBuilder).deleteFromSourceAndMoveToTargetSftpBuilder(anyString(), anyString(), anyString(), any())
//                .build();
//        doReturn(uriBuilder).when(scaRouteBuilder).deleteFromSourceAndMoveToTargetSftpBuilder(anyString(), anyString(), anyString(), any()).build();
//        when(scaRouteBuilder.deleteFromSourceAndMoveToTargetSftpBuilder(anyString(), anyString(), anyString(), any(PaymentHubConfigLookup.class)))
//                .thenReturn(uriBuilder);

        scaService.process("", paymentHubConfigLookup);

        verify(scaService).process("", paymentHubConfigLookup);
    }
```

I already had several stubs for mocking this code above that I just commented out atm, but still, it doesn't mock at all.

Any other ways to unit test this?. Thanks

I also added the stacktrace below

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.cwt.bpg.paymenthub.service.ScaService.process(ScaService.java:65)
    at com.cwt.bpg.paymenthub.service.ScaServiceTest.existingFileTest(ScaServiceTest.java:80)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1$1.evaluate(DefaultInternalRunner.java:54)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:99)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:105)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:40)
    at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:163)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:119)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:414)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

For reference:
The Line 65 that reports an NPE is the code with
.build();
in it.

However, I already stubbed the response of this with uriBuilder, I would expect with this stubbing, the actual URIBuilder thrown is already mocked from my first sample stub, and that when .build() is triggered, it would have already understood the mock somehow and throw a mock response instead of an NPE.

Comment: Without the stack trace of the NPE, it's hard to help. Presumably you are not stubbing some return value that you need.

Comment: I added a sample stacktrace with my first stub uncommented.

Comment: You need to uncomment the line that stubs `scaRouteBuilder.deleteFromSourceAndMoveToTargetSftpBuilder` but also check whether `config` or `routeBuilder` are null.

Comment: config and routebuilders were already stub and when checking if it has contents on debug, it says there is and hence those seems to be fine anyway. I already had RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS for this anyway and hence expected any further calls realted to this mocks will be mocked anyway. scaRouteBuilder.deleteFromSourceAndMoveToTargetSftpBuilder is already uncommented when I run the code for stacktrace purposes above. I just had it commented out since the stubbing doesnt seem to work anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem here ist the `when(mockObject.mockedMethod()).thenReturn()` form of stubbing the method calls.

In this form the real method to be stubbed is actually executed and only its result is replaced by Mockito. Since the Mock of `ScaRouteBuilder` gets `null`s passed as constructor parameters placing them in the mock objects properties the `build()` method throws a NPE when accessing these  properties.

To avoid this use the `doReturn().when(mockedObject).mockedMethod()` form. This intercepts and avoids the call to the real method in the mocked object.

Alternatively you can try `@Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)` on `ScaRouteBuilder`

https://rieckpil.de/creating-deep-stubs-with-mockito-to-chain-method-stubbing/

Comment: oh, thanks, this worked somehow, will read more on this, greatly appreciated. thx.